# How to convert string array response to javascript 2D array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I am creating the following string response in JSP:

```
[[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]]
```

and getting this response in jQuery.

But I am getting it as 1D array, I need array to be like that only

I am getting respone as

```
var a = "[[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]]";
```

Comment: That'd be JSON data most likely, so look into using a json library, or alternatively, as a worst+last ditch effort, `eval()` it.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have 2D arrays... You can have arrays of arrays though, which is exactly what you're getting in your example

Comment: var set = eval(a) => then you can use set[0][0] to get your first array of data set[0][0][2] == 3

Comment: Yes ,  eval is working fine , can we say , it will work on IE and other browsers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible methods:

1. `var arr = JSON.parse(a);`
2. `var arr = eval(a);`

Comment: However `eval` is not recommended if the string is not generated by your script itself. (I +1'd your answer though)

Comment: @Derek: yes and no.  `eval` on the front end is a lot less troublesome then `eval` on the backend; however you do have to be cautious, since it is an XSS entry point.  So long as your variable (`a`) is populated from a trusted source, your users shouldn't have to worry.  The other downside of `eval` is the inherent performance hit, since the browser has to re-interpret the code.

Answer (score 1):

To create an arbitrarily nested array (or any object supported in JSON, for that matter) from it's string representation, you can use the `JSON.parse` method.

```
var arr = JSON.parse("[[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]]");
```

Comment: do i need  , any library to include for it to work , is it IE supported ?

Comment: @user629804 It will work in IE8+, you can use the [json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to add support for older browsers.

Comment: thanks ,Peter , i will go by eval approach , as it seems IE safe

Comment: @user629804 - You can use jQuery. JSON conversion is included there.

Comment: Yeah - jQuery includes JSON2 as a shim if it is not present in the browser. Also, `eval` is never to be considered safe. It is kind of like having a gun with a safety on on a coat hanger in the nursery. If you take precautions it is probably safe, but enough fooling around and someone *will* get a foot shot off.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting JSON, which is a string. You need to parse it into a JavaScript object.

```
var object_a = JSON.parse(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(arr):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse`:

```
var matrix = JSON.parse(a):
```

For support below IE8, use jQuery for that. (Lucky if your website already using jQuery! `;)` )